# How do I incorporate OIDC roles into Razor page role-based authorization (.Net 7.0)

Tags: c#, openid-connect, razor-pages

I'm trying to implement role-based authorization in a Razor page web app on .Net 7.0. I'm using Auth0 as the auth provider, and that all works fine. I have added an Action on Auth0 to include the role information in the token, and I can extract that information from the User object's Claims collection.

I would like to be able to use that role information to allow/deny access to individual pages using the Convention.AuthorizePage("/Pagename", "PolicyName") pattern in AddRazorPages, where the policy would be defined based on user role e.g.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("RequireAdministratorRole",
         policy => policy.RequireRole("Administrator"));
});
```

What do I need to do convert the role from Auth0 into a Role that is assigned to the User?

The documentation I have found on creating roles with the RoleManager all seem to rely on a backing store, but I'm outsourcing this to an auth provider (where I can set up roles and assign users to them).

TIA

Answer (score 0):

This should all be in Program.cs:

Add Identity:

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => { options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true; })
.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Get rid of the funky claim names:

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;
```

Add authentication via OIDC:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(o =>{
o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
o.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;}).AddCookie().AddOpenIdConnect(o =>{
o.MetadataAddress = "Your AuthO OIDC endpoint";    
o.SignInScheme = "Cookies";    
o.Authority = "Your AuthO url";
o.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
o.SkipUnrecognizedRequests = true;
o.ClientId = "clientId";
o.ClientSecret = "secret";
o.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
o.UsePkce = true;
o.Scope.Add(o.ClientId);
o.SaveTokens = true;    
o.SignedOutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:63721";
o.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
{
    NameClaimType = "name",
    RoleClaimType = "role",

};
o.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
{
    OnAccessDenied = async ad =>
    {

    },
    OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async rd =>
    {
        
    },
    OnAuthenticationFailed = async af =>
    {

    },
    OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async rec =>
    {

    },
    OnTokenResponseReceived = tok =>
    {
        //here's your token
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var token = handler.ReadJwtToken(tok.TokenEndpointResponse.AccessToken);

        var claims = tok.Principal?.Claims.ToList();

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
};});
```

Add Authorization:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(o =>{
o.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();});
```

Comment: Thanks, I will have a go. Not sure where I would get the OIDC endpoint from, I am currently using AddAuth0WebAppAuthentication (from Auth0.AspNetCore.Authentication package), which only requires Domain and ClientId.

Comment: It should be a link from AuthO ending with something like this: .well-known/openid-configuration

Comment: I think my issue may actually be the way I am adding the Auth0 roles into the token, the sample Action I have used looks a lot different from a (being deprecated) Rule I  have found in the docs for the Auth0.AspNetCore.Authentication package, which they suggest should attach roles in a format that Asp.net will natively understand.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. I converted the Rule to an Action as 
`exports.onExecutePostLogin = async (event, api) => {
  const assignedRoles = (event.authorization || {}).roles;
  
  if (event.authorization) {
    api.idToken.setCustomClaim('http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role', assignedRoles);
    api.accessToken.setCustomClaim('http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role', assignedRoles);
  }
}` and the roles flow through to asp.net correctly now